# During the assembly of the Surveyor 3 probe, someone _sneezed_ a TV camera

Tags: prepositions, ielts

Can someone sneeze a camera,
or should they sneeze *AT* the camera?

This is an extract from an IELTS practice test. Because the dictionary says "sneeze at smt", I had to put another word from the text, i.e. "installed", which fits better grammatically. However, I then suddenly found in the answer keys that the correct answer is "sneezed".

It is obvious by the context that the question is focusing on sneezing at a camera, but the grammatical structure confused me.

Please could you comment?

Comment: How many dictionaries have you checked in to see what they say about whether 'sneeze' is used transitively?

Comment: [This](http://www.p-papers.com/24571.html) may help with that transitive use. I would, however, assume that since no test is infallible, there may be a typo (or a missed word) in the test question. Your assumptions seem to be correct (google tells me it is unlikely that someone sneezed the whole camera into the probe), I would not worry about it too much :)

Comment: @oerkelens http://www.smallestvideocameras.com/images/microcameras-medigus/1-2-microcamera-medigus-big.jpg and http://www4.pcmag.com/media/images/294362-fraunhofer-microcamera.jpg?thumb=y

Comment: @mplungjan: I should have added _during the Surveyor project_. :)

Comment: Thank you everyone for your valuable comments. @EdwinAshworth - I've checked only the Longman dictionary. But it has quite a lot collocations and examples. oerkelens - I would not worry about it if it would not change the way I answered the question: because of the missing preposition, I had to select different words from the text to put into the answer (actually, -ing word)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is almost certainly a typo for

> During assembly of the Surveyor 3 probe, someone _____ **on** a TV camera.

It's actually a fairly famous incident in NASA history:

[image: Sneeze]

From Wharton, [*Life at the Limits*](http://books.google.com/books?id=7t8IQ1x6x3IC&pg=PA244&lpg=PA244&dq=Surveyor+3+probe+someone+sneezed&source=bl&ots=sB4V7S-5A7&sig=aRD-dT71sLbwdOfqH8mpFawvUbs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2-VYU-ajNIKCyAG0g4G4DQ&ved=0CEQQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Yes, it looks like everyone agrees it's a typo.